# Rails 4: Specified Unicorn in Procfile, but Webrick is executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I am using Rails 4.0.1 and I want to run unicorn as my web server, but when I execute rails s, Webrick is used instead (the unicorn gem is in my Gemfile, so it can't be that).

This is my Procfile:

```
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

And this is the unicorn.rb file:

```
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

What is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rails server` doesn't use your `Procfile`; that's for [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman). Start your application with `foreman` instead:

```
bundle exec foreman start
```

If you want `rails server` to use Unicorn as well, you can include the [unicorn-rails](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails) gem.

Answer (score 3):

*I am adding this as a general help article to those that have landed here because of a related search on Google.*

If you want to run Unicorn then add this in your project

### Gemfile

```
# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'unicorn-rails'
```

Then in your terminal run `bundle install`

You will then get something like this in your terminal that shows that you are now using Unicorn.

```
=> Booting Unicorn
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
I, [2014-10-24T18:39:41.074259 #32835]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:3000 fd=8
I, [2014-10-24T18:39:41.074399 #32835]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2014-10-24T18:39:41.075407 #32835]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2014-10-24T18:39:41.076712 #32836]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=32836
I, [2014-10-24T18:39:41.237335 #32836]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

**Additional Reading**
[Unicorn Rails](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails)
[Deploying to Heroku with Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start everything by running [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/), e.g.,

```
$ foreman start
```

Otherwise you're just starting up Rails' default server.

See this [Getting Started](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) guide for further background info.